Field not included in result documents but matches exists filter
I'm using Elasticsearch 7.10 in the AWS OpenSearch service. I have an index for which rotation is used as I'm storing time series data. I use an index template to define the _mappings which will be applied for each new index that gets created whenever the index gets rotated.
I've recently updated the template via PUT _template because I need to add a new field to the documents that are being stored in my indices. I can see that GET _template is showing the new field along with the datatype I specified. And I can see that GET {index name}/_mappings on one of the new indices also shows the new field with its correct datatype.
When I do an exists query such as:
{
  "size": 20,
  "query":
     {
       "bool": {
         "must": {
           "exists": {
             "field": "new_field"
           }
         }
       }
     },
  "_source": ["new_field",...]
}

I get some hits. But the documents that get returned don't include new_field in them. I would expect these documents to include this field.
I've tested specifically indexinf a document containing new_field using POST {index_name}/_doc. When I do a query to fetch that document back again:
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "_id": "{the _id ES created for it}"
    }
  }
}

I get the document and it has all the fields but not new_field.
The cluster also includes the Kibana plugin and I get the same behaviour in Kibana. In Kibana, I've updated the "Index Pattern" for these indices. When I click the "Refresh field list" button it shows me new_field. And when I go to "Discover", new_field is available as an auto-complete option when adding a filter, but it doesn't appear in the "Available fields" list. Just like with the REST API, I can do an exists query in Kibana and get a bunch of documents back, but the documents returned don't include new_field.
So why is new_field not visible in my documents when it apparently seems to be present?

According to the documentation "exists" do not return anything if The field in the source JSON is null or []
The field has "index" : false and "doc_values" : false set in the mapping
The length of the field value exceeded an ignore_above setting in the mapping
The field value was malformed and ignore_malformed was defined in the mapping Source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html   How did you change the mapping?
